# Why does extracting a date from a dataframe work when its outside of a function, but not when it is used inside a function? R

Tags: r, function, loops, date

I'm new to coding in general, and have a feeling that this problem is more a structural thing than a syntax thing.

I have the following dataframe:

```
mm <- c(0,0,1,30,0,50)
dates <- as.Date(c("2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", "2020-06-04", "2020-06-05", "2020-06-06"))
weather <- data.frame(dates, mm)
```

I want to create a function and loop to concatenate a string and a date if the mm of rain is 35 or more for the given date.

```
testfunction <- function() {
  if(i >= 35) {
    print(paste(c(
      "here's the date:", 
      weather$dates[weather$mm>=35]),
      sep = " "))
  }}

for (i in weather$mm) {
  testfunction()}
```

Now, if I run the date extraction line outside of the function by itself:

```
 weather$dates[weather$mm>=35]

> "2020-06-06"
```

But when I run it through the function within the loop:

```
> "here's the date:" "18419"
```

Ignoring the expected string output, why is the date extraction not returning the same thing as outside the function?

Comment: It is just a property of the `Date` class that is coerced to integer storage mode.  Can you wrap with `as.character`

Comment: Simply, remove the nested `c` in `paste`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just that the `Date` class of 'dates' column is coerced to `integer` values while it is concatenated (`c`) with a `character` vector

```
paste(c(
        "here's the date:", weather$dates))
#[1] "here's the date:" "18414"            "18415"            "18416"            "18417"            "18418"            "18419"
```

We could avoid this by converting to `character` with `as.character`

```
paste(c(
        "here's the date:", as.character(weather$dates)))
```

The function can be changed as

```
testfunction <- function() {
  if(i >= 35) {
    print(paste(c(
      "here's the date:", 
      as.character(weather$dates)[weather$mm>=35]),
      sep = " "))
  }}
```

and then apply

```
for (i in weather$mm) {
  testfunction()}
```

-output

```
[1] "here's the date:" "2020-06-06"
```

---

Also, it is not entirely clear why it needs to be concatenated (as in the comments).  If the intention is to create  a single string (currently, it returns multiple strings as part of concatenation), we can use `paste` as

```
paste("here's the date: ", weather$dates[weather$mm>=35])
```

---

If we need to print in next line, use `cat` while `paste` the element with `sep` as `\n`

```
testfunction <- function() {
  if(i >= 35) {
    cat(paste(
      "here's the date:", 
      weather$dates[weather$mm>=35],
      sep = "\n"), "\n")
  }}

for (i in weather$mm) {
   testfunction()}
#here's the date:
#2020-06-06
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great and I get your explanation. I kept them separate as I havent figured out how to include a line break within a long string yet.

This whole program is checking weather forecasts for certain amounts of rain, and will email me when certain flags are hit. The code you helped me with above will be for the body of the email.

Comment: @Coldest Did you meant something like in the update

Comment: Yes sir, thank you so much! I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I already tried to upvote but because my account is literally brand new, I don't have enough reputation to vote myself.

Answer (score 0):

```r
    mm <- c(0,0,1,30,0,50)
dates <- as.character(c("2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", "2020-06-04", "2020-06-05", "2020-06-06"))
weather <- data.frame(dates, mm)

testfunction <- function(x) {
    if(x >= 35) {
        print(paste(c(
            "here's the date:", 
            weather$dates[weather$mm>=35]),
            sep = " "))
    }}

for (i in weather$mm) {
    testfunction(i)
}
#> [1] "here's the date:" "2020-06-06"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>